# Visual Studio analyzer on custom file extension

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have created a Visual Studio C/C++ project in my Visual Studio solution, using Visual Studio 2022 Professional.

This project contains C files, some of them with the `*.c` file extension, some named `*.ppc` and some named `*.c_m`. They are all basically C files. I want the Visual Studio analyzer to analyze all of them as C files, providing me with full syntax highlighting and quick feedback on syntax errors.

Through `Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> File Extension`, I added the "`ppc`" and "`c_m`" file extensions to the list, setting "`Editing Experience`" to "`Microsoft Visual C++`". This provided basic syntax highlighting on standard C keywords, such as "`const`", "`struct`" or "`int`", but it doesn't detect custom names and types.

Through right-clicking a `c_m` file, selecting `Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General`, I found an option "`Item Type`" that was previously set to "`Does not participate in build`". I changed it to "`C/C++ compiler`", but it had no effect.

If I write an obvious error in the code, it is not detected by the analyzer.

How can I make Visual Studio treat my `*.c_m` and `*.ppc` files just the same as the `*.c` files?